# Passing STL List iterator to a function

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Don't understand why I have to increment/decrement the list iterator to make this function call work.  Is there a less convoluted way to call this?  Referring to the nested for loop, the "insertDDNode(*(--DD_it), *(++DD_it), data[j-i], data[j+1]);" segment.

```
void insertDDNode(DataNode *l, DataNode *r);
vector<DataNode*> data;
list<DDNode*> DDT;

int main()
{
  unsigned int n = 5;
  // insert data into vector structure
  data.push_back(new DataNode(0, -1, 13));
  data.push_back(new DataNode(1, 0, 2));
  data.push_back(new DataNode(2, 2, -14));
  data.push_back(new DataNode(3, 4, 18));
  data.push_back(new DataNode(4, 5, 67));
  data.push_back(new DataNode(5, 6, 91));
  vector<DataNode*> :: iterator it = data.begin();
  list<DDNode*> :: iterator DD_it;

  while(it != data.end())
  {
    insertDDNode(*it, *(it+1));
    it++;
    if((*it)->i == data.back()->i){break;}
  }

  DD_it = DDT.begin();
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
     {
       insertDDNode(*(--DD_it), *(++DD_it), data[j-i], data[j+1]);
       DD_it++;
     }
    DD_it++;
  }
}

void insertDDNode(DataNode *left, DataNode *right)
{
  T div_diff = (right->y - left->y) / (right->x - left->x);
  DDT.push_back(new DDNode(*left, *right, div_diff));
  left->r = right->l = DDT.back();
}
```

Comment: Does this program compile and run?

Comment: The line `insertDDNode(*(--DD_it), *(++DD_it), data[j-i], data[j+1]);` has unpredictable behavior, because you can't rely on the order in which arguments of a function call will be evaluated.

Comment: @AndyProwl, this is called `undefined behaviour` by the standards, and is referenced as such most of the time.

Comment: @vonbrand: no, it is not UB. UB means that the implementation is free to do anything. Here, the only thing which is unknown is the order of evaluation of the arguments. If the iterator was a built-in type, then you would be right.

Comment: @AndyProwl, it _is_ undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to assume nobody does such nonsense, and thus select the order in which to do the operations as it sees fit. I.e., it is not _defined_ what will happen, and that is the definition of "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @vonbrand: no, that is not the definition of "undefined behavior". Undefined Behavior means that the implementation can do *anything*, including displaying on your monitor the words "Give me a cookie". Here implementations are only free to choose any order for the evaluation of the arguments, so the possible behavior is unpredictable but not unrestricted.

Comment: @AndyProwl, the standard defines in minute detail what each _legal_ construct does. If a construct can be interpreted in different ways, there is no single interpretation, and it is _undefined_. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior.

Comment: @vonbrand: I stand by my statement. If you will find in the Standard the wording which says that such a call is undefined behavior, I will believe you. Till then, I will believe 1.9/5, which explicitly mentions "Scalar objects" - and that's not our case.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I think it is UB. Rationale: The are two modifications of `DD_it` without a sequence point between the two. That's AFAIK typical UB situation. The unpredictability of parameters evaluation order is another bad thing on top of that.

Comment: @wilx: Please note, that C++11 eleven defines the "sequenced before" relation slightly different than C++03's "sequence points". The two modifications are not modifications of a scalar object, and you know they are not allowed to be interleaved, so their order is undefined, but that's everything. If it were a scalar object, then it would be UB. The relevant paragraph is 1.9/15

Comment: @vonbrand: sorry, I mistyped the paragraph number in the previous comment: it is 1.9/15 and not 1.9/5. I dropped a "1"

Comment: Andy Prowl is both right and wrong. That line *does* produce *undefined behaviour*, but the cause you quote actually only produces *unspecified behaviour*, which is a different thing. The undefined behaviour is caused separately.

Comment: @DeadMG: How come it does produce undefined behavior? 1.9/15 only says it's undefined for scalars